How to upgrade a MacBook Pro (11,4) to macOS Monterey?
My MacBook Pro (11,4) is outfitted with macOS BigSur. A non-admin account provides access to the machine. I'd like to upgrade it to macOS Monterey, however, admin account is needed.
I am okay with backing up (Time Machine) the non-admin account and reformatting the machine from scratch with macOS Monterey.
That being said, if I am making his harder than it needs to be I'd like to know. What is the simplest path to upgrading to macOS Monterey?

What happened to the admin account? Have you just forgotten the password, or ... something else? The OS is a completely separate thing from the user accounts, and should not normally need to be erased.

The admin account password was forgotten: the answer below allowed all accounts to be reset and then upgrade the OS

As per this thread on Apple’s official support site:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253449314?sortBy=rank

How to reset computer password.
Intel Computer

Restart computer and immediately hold Command+R keys.
Top Tool Bar >> Utilities >> Terminal.
Type resetpassword as one word and no spaces.
Press Return key.
Follow the prompts and remember the new password.

Apple Silicon Computer

Choose Apple menu >> Shut Down.
Press and hold the power button on your Mac until you see “Loading startup options.”
Click “Options,” then click “Continue.”
Top Tool Bar >> Utilities >> Terminal
Type resetpassword as one word and no spaces.
Press Return key.
Follow the prompts and remember the new password.

